# C++ - How do I get moving dots to continuously loop?

Tags: c++, oop

I am having trouble getting my moving dot program to work properly. I have the program to where the dots move to the right like they are supposed to, but how do I get them to loop back around so it looks like they are continuously moving instead of moving off the page? The block of code I need to edit to make this happen is below. I hope someone can help and thanks again in advance!

```
void advanceDots(XPoint dots[], unsigned num_dots, XWindowAttributes &w){
  int s = num_dots;
  for(s = 0; s < num_dots; s++){
    if(s < num_dots){
        dots[s].x++;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need another variable to keep track if you are currently "moving left" vs "moving right".  Then swap when you hit a boundary.

Something like this:

```
bool isMovingLeft = false;

void advanceDots(XPoint dots[], unsigned num_dots, XWindowAttributes &w)
{
  if (isMovingLeft && (dots[0].x <= 0))
  {
      isMovingLeft = false;
  }
  else if (!isMovingLeft && dots[num_dots-1] >= w.width)
  {
      isMovingLeft = true;
  }

  int increment = isMovingLeft ? -1 : 1;
  int s = num_dots;
  for(s = 0; s < num_dots; s++)
  {
      dots[s].x += increment;      
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Normally there is some kind of boundary for a position. I will assume it's in XWindowAttributes just to give you an example:

To make the dots "go back" to the beginning instead of "moving off the page" you can just set them back like this:

```
//I dont know the structure of XWindowAttributes so i will define one just for the example!

struct XWindowAttributes
{
    int x_size; // the maximal size of the window in the x direction
};

void advanceDots(XPoint dots[], unsigned num_dots, XWindowAttributes &w)
{
    for(int s = 0; s < num_dots; s++)
    {
        XPoint& dot = dots[s];
        dots.x++;

        if(dots.x >= w.x_size)
        {
            dots.x = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You helped out a lot!

Comment: You are welcome! Consider using selbies version though as it's more clean and generally better.